# How do you perform an operation on a phrase *only* if it's outside backticks?

Tags: python

E.g. say you have the line:

```
`Here's an example.` And another example.
```

How could you change **only** the second "example" to uppercase? E.g:

```
`Here's an example.` And another EXAMPLE.
```

Comment: Do you have to handle escaped backticks as well?

Comment: No (some fluff to get to necessary number of characters to allow a No as a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split by backtick and then make the replacement in the even indexed chunks:

```
s = "`Here's an example.` And another example."
res = "`".join(part if i % 2 else part.replace("example", "EXAMPLE") 
                  for i, part in enumerate(s.split("`"))
              )
```

Or, with a regular expression you could look ahead and only make the replacement when the number of backticks that follow it, is even:

```
import re

s = "`Here's an example.` And another example."
res = re.sub(r"\bexample\b(?=([^`]*`[^`]*`)*[^`]*$)", "EXAMPLE", s)
```

Comment: Great to have two examples. I like the first example - a lot easier to understand!